# How to fix error in chrome extension code js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building my first chrome extension, but it doesn't work. Google chrome can read the manifest and icon logo, but it doesn't work after that. It is supposed to have a click function (javascript) to different background images. So when you click on them it will change the background of any page.

javascript file

```
function click(e){
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(" + image[e.target.id]
        +"'"});
window.close();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var divs = document.querySelectionALL('div'); 
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
}
});


var images = {
file1: 'file1.jpg',
file2:'file2.jpg',

}
```

Comment: You need to list those images in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and expand the URL like chrome.runtime.getURL(image[e.target.id])

Comment: web_accessible_resources should be in the manifest  or javascript ? and then expand the URL to ... backgroundImage = chrome.runtime.getURL(image[e.target.id]

Comment: It's in manifest, you can find examples by googling.

Comment: thx. But the help I find by googling is not working either. I must have some kind of bug in my javascript

Comment: Make sure you've reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page. Use devtools to debug the code.

Comment: The manifest does not work now after I added web_accesible_resources in the manifest: 
 "web_accessible_resources": [
 "images/file1.png",
 "style/file1.css",
 "script/file1.js",
 "script/main.js"
 ]

Comment: It means you've made a typo or forgot a comma or put it in the wrong place, something like that, which I can't guess from comments.

Comment: Could you write an example if I copy/paste my codes for manifest and javascript ? Then just add/correct my code.

Comment: No, there are tons of examples you can find trivially by using google search.